# Which Gdiplus::Graphics::DrawImage function should I use?

Tags: c++, gdi+

I want paste a (x,y,w,h) subrectangle from src to dest, so that the (x,y) source pixel appears as the (0,0) dest pixel. I'm having a difficulty deciding which of the gazillion overloads does this. Right now my code looks like this, which obviously doesn't work:

```
auto_ptr<Gdiplus::Graphics> g(Gdiplus::Graphics::FromHDC(pDC->GetSafeHdc()));
g->DrawImage(png, r.top, r.bottom, r.Width(), r.Height());
g->Flush();
```

It doesn't work because the (x,y) source pixel appears as the (x,y) destination pixel, whereas I want it to appear as the (0,0) destination pixel. The source and destination rectangles should have the same size but different offsets, instead of the same offset.

[Edit]
Nevermind, I found the overloaded function I need. Turns all I had to add was the destination (x,y) offset in front, and UnitPixel at the end.

```
auto_ptr<Gdiplus::Graphics> g(Gdiplus::Graphics::FromHDC(pDC->GetSafeHdc()));
g->DrawImage(png, 0, 0, r.left, r.top, r.Width(), r.Height(), Gdiplus::UnitPixel);
g->Flush();
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the gdiplus, but in similar cases I guess you need to pass png's width and height instead of r's. Also be sure that an image fit into the available rect.

Comment: r has the png width/height. It was done before the code I pasted.

Comment: I removed the "solved" tag from your title -- since you found the solution yourself, you should post that as an answer to your own question and accept it, that way you're using the built-in mechanism for marking a question answered that the site provides. I think there's even a badge for doing so.

Comment: I've tried to do it before but the 'Answer your own question' button never works. I don't know if this is because I use Chrome or something else. I mean I click it but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone would work, they work equally well. They are mostly just aliases for each other. The one I guess you are using would be [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536049%28VS.85%29.aspx) which states that:

> x [in] REAL Real number that specifies
>   the x-coordinate of the upper-left
>   corner of the destination rectangle at
>   which to draw the image.
>
> y [in] REAL Real number that specifies
>   the y-coordinate of the upper-left
>   corner of the destination rectangle at
>   which to draw the image.

Try to set the x and y values to 0 instead, so that the call becomes:

```
auto_ptr<Gdiplus::Graphics> g(Gdiplus::Graphics::FromHDC(pDC->GetSafeHdc()));
g->DrawImage(png, 0, 0, r.Width(), r.Height());
g->Flush();
```

Other than that you would have to be more specific as to what "Doesn't work". Is it incorrectly drawn? Is it not drawn at all? Is the png correctly loaded? 
If nothing is drawn I suggest you check the return value (which is a  [**Status**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534175%28VS.85%29.aspx)) from DrawImage which should point you in the correct direction.

---

EDIT

Ok, so if you don't want it to be mapped as src(0, 0) to dest(0, 0) I guess you could use [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536039%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead. This will let you decide

> src[x|y] [in] REAL Real number that
>   specifies the [x|y]-coordinate of the
>   upper-left corner of the portion of
>   the source image to be drawn.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work because the (x,y) source pixel appears as the (x,y) destination pixel, whereas I want it to appear as the (0,0) destination pixel. The source and destination rectangles should have the same size but different offsets, instead of the same offset.